# How to manually load a GlimmerComponent (angle brackets component) in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have small experiment where I use webpack for Ember development instead of ember-cli. I'd like to test the new GlimmerComponent (angle brackets component), but I can't get this to work. [Here is my code](https://github.com/Mercateo/component-check/commit/c8b4df0b6e342e48d12fab480e1d5ca4417f9195#diff-b2401adead1e91da3f73f81ef649aba2R2).

I've included the Canary version of Ember and set the feature flag. The `Ember.GlimmerComponent` object is available. But the component will not be loaded/created, if I use it in my template. I can however use a normal `{{my-component}}`, if I place it manually on `Ember.TEMPLATES`. The templates are precompiled with `require('components-ember/ember-template-compiler').precompile`.

Note: Please no discussion about webpack vs. ember-cli. This is a personal research project and I probably learned more things about Ember with fiddling it into webpack by now as by reading the docs.

Comment: You might already have checked this, but I believe angle bracket components also require specific support from the template compiler.

Comment: I _think_ it should work with `require('components-ember/ember-template-compiler').precompile` on canary.

Comment: I checked the code, and angle bracket support is implemented as a plugin in the template compiler. I am trying to understand the loading code, I don't know whether the plugin is enabled by default or if it has to be enabled manually.

Comment: It seems it should be enabled by default after all. Might be worth checking though. If you can inspect your precompiled template, you should be able to see whether your angle component was recognized by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort so far. I think I can check this in the next 24 hours.